# Create a model method for a shared app based on project?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I can't seem to figure out a good solution to this issue:

I've got an app that has a shared `User` model (`AbstractUser`)

This app is shared among multiple projects (which all have their own apps)

The structure looks like something like this:

- Project X

  - App A
  - App B
- Project Y

  - App A
  - App C
  - App D
- Project Z

  - App A
  - App E
  - App F

I'm at a point where I need to add a model method on the `User` model in Project Z to make life easier. It would do some business logic involving other models from the other related apps in Project Z.

I cannot add that method directly to the `User` model, because then the other projects would fail - since they would not contain all the referenced models.

What is the best way to accomplish this in Django?

Should I make a `ProjectZUser` that inherits the shared `User` model and add the methods on that model?

Comment: Can you just define a function that takes a user instance as an argument instead? E.g., instead of `user.my_method(42)`, `my_method(user, 42)`

Comment: I am concerned about annotating some data onto that model specifically (or being able to access it on a per-model iteration in the template). Is there a way to do that with a random function?